# What does this Blockchain info mean? Clueless

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info

[image: Block Chain explorer]

This is the info but it'S all greek to me. I'm pretty nerdy about PC's but clueless in terms of bitcoins. Tell me where I can get definitive comprehensive information would be a help too.

Answer (score 2):

No it’s not greek :-)
You’re first step in understanding might be to have a look at the book „Mastering Bitcoin“ by Andreas M. Antonopoulos. And if you need a translation, you might want to look here: https://www.transifex.com/bitcoinbook/public/.
The second resource is „www.bitcoin.org“, where you can find a description of the whole eco system, also in many languages.

The picture displays info about a wallet address, and it’s transactions, followed by  corresponding data to handle such a transaction in the bitcoin network. At the top left you can see the bitcoin address (1CYQ…), and it’s hash representation (look into the references I gave, why you would have hash representations). In the top middle section you see the amount of transactions for this address, and to the right a graphical representation of the address („QR code“). With QR codes you can e.g. transfer information between mobile devices via their integrated cameras. So if someone wants to send you money, he just scans the picture, instead of typing the address.
And the bottom section shows the previous transactions for this address, how values got „transferred“ from source addresses to target addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This picture describes transactions, which are things that move money around between addresses. You can search for the incoming and outgoing payments to a particular address.